# ResponseEntity body lost between two webservice calls

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

I have a webservice which calls another WS and returns the response from the second WS. It looks like so:

```
// MyController
public ResponseEntity<Foo> requestFooController(@RequestBody @Valid Bar request) {
     return this.myService.requestFooService(request);
}

//MyService
ResponseEntity<Foo> requestFooService(Bar request) {
  Buzz improvedRequest = ...
  return this.secondWS.secondRequestFoo(improvedRequest);
}
```

When I call the API through Postman, I receive a HTTP OK response with an empty body. Yet, when I'm in debug mode I can see that the service is returning a `ResponseEntity` with a body. The headers are not lost though.

I changed my code like so and it works fine:

```
// MyController
public ResponseEntity<Foo> requestFooController(@RequestBody @Valid Bar request) {
     ResponseEntity<Foo> tmp = this.myService.requestFooService(request);
     return ResponseEntity.status(tmp.getStatusCode()).body(tmp.getBody());
}
```

Now through Postman I do have the expected body. However, I don't understand the behaviour. I thought that maybe it's due to the fact that the body is some kind of stream that can be read once or something similar. But from reading the source code I don't see anything that could explain this behaviour.

I'm using the Netflix-stack (so HTTP calls between the two WS are made through a `Feign` client).

Any idea why I'm getting this result?

EDIT:
More details on my stask:
SpringBoot 1.5.3.RELEASE
Feign 2.0.5

Comment: Which versions of spring-boot are you using? There is one version-specific bug that caused the name of the multipart body to be lost and then doesn't match parameters.  You're using feign, but are you using eureka and zuul in your Netflix stack?

Comment: Yes I'm using Zuul and Eureka. I could try to bypass zuul and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug that causes the named body of an HTTP MultiPart POST to fail. The symptom of this is that you make a POST request with a body, and Spring-Boot can't match it up to an endoint. The exception I see is:

```
2019-01-23 15:22:45.046 DEBUG 1639 --- [io-8080-exec-10] .w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : Failed to resolve argument 3 of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile'
    org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present
```

Zuul is doing caching of the request in order to re-try multiple times.  In this process, it fails to preserve the named field for the binary body. You may find it working if you preface the request with zuul. So instead of http://myserver.com/myservice/endpoint use zuul in the path: http://myserver.com/zuul/myservice/endpoint

That will effectively avoid the saving of the request and the retry mechanism.

[More details are available on this issue in Zuul's GitHub Bug List](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2903).

Comment: I'm upgrading to spring-boot 2.1.3 to resolve this issue in production.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'll check if I've a similar issue in the debug log. I guess it will be another argument to push the upgrade :)